# AMPScript dynamic drop down list in Smart Capture

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

In my Smart Capture I have 2 different but related inputs, Country and State.
Is there any way of relating it via AMPScript in order to select a country in one dropdown and automatically the input State dropdown gets adapted to the related values?

I know in javascript is usual to do dynamic drop down lists with country & state, but I would like to include it in the AMPScript code.

Comment: Can you please show us a copy of your code?

Comment: What I don't know es what kind of code insert in my Smart Capture. Is what I am asking for, some AMPScript example to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly you like to dynamically change available values in the second dropdown as soon as the value of the first dropdown changes?

If so, then this isn't possible using AMPscript as AMPscript is rendered on the server. You will need to use a clientside technology like javascript to do so.